# Styling Facebook register button

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

I am using the Facebook registration plugin for registering `FB` and `non-FB` users to my site. For `non-FB` users I would like to retain the styling of my site and have a different color for the button.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.  Please check [similar question in Quora](http://www.quora.com/How-can-we-style-the-new-Facebook-Registration-form)